# Automatically deriving show instances for GADTs

Tags: haskell, gadt, deriving

Assume I have a complex GADT which with many hidden type parameters as constructors:

```
data T where
  A :: Num n => n -> T
  B :: (Num n, Integral m) => n -> m -> T
  C :: Floating a => [a] -> T
  -- and so on
  Z :: Num n => n -> n -> T
```

I want to make this datatype showable without having to manually write the instance. Problem is, that since `Show` isn't a superclass of `Num` anymore, adding a simple `deriving instance Show T` isn't enough for the compiler to infer that it has to add `Show` constraints to all the internal hidden type parameters.

For each hidden type parameter, it outputs something like

```
Could not deduce (Show n) arising from a use of 'showsPrec'
from the context Num n
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             A :: forall n. Num n => n -> T
...
Possible fix:
  add (Show n) to the context of the data constructor 'A'
```

Adding a `Show` constraint to the datatype isn't an option either, since it limits the possible inhabitants of `T`. It seems like `deriving instanec Show T` should introduce the constraint `Show` on the hidden data types, although I am not sure.

How can I go about this?

Comment: If adding the constraint will limit the inhabitants, the deriving mechanism certainly won't do it for you, nor would you want it to.

Comment: @Lazersmoke I mean adding the constraints to the derived instance. This doesn't limit inhabitants, it only constructs the `Show` instance in a coherent way.

Comment: there is no good Show instance for T, no matter what you do, unless you restrict all tyvars (including existentials) to Show.

Comment: If the `A` constructor is allowed to contain a non-showable number, how would you expect to show such `T` value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had an interesting thought, not sure how practical it is.  But if you want `T` to be showable when the parameters are showable, but also usable with not showable parameters, you could parameterize `T` over a constraint, using `ConstraintKinds`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ConstraintKinds #-}

import Data.Kind

data T :: (* -> Constraint) -> * where
    A :: (Num n, c n) => n -> T c
    B :: (Num n, c n, Integral m, c m) => n -> m -> T c
    ...
```

Then `T Show` will be showable... *maybe*

```
deriving instance Show (T Show)
```

(with `StandaloneDeriving` extension) will work, but at the very least, `T` is showable in principle and you could write the instance manually.

Though my practical advice is to reify the existentials.  An existential type is equivalent to the collection of its observations.  For example, if you had a class like

```
class Foo a where
   getBool :: a -> Bool
   getInt  :: a -> Int
```

then the existential

```
data AFoo where
   AFoo :: Foo a => a
```

is exactly equivalent to `(Bool,Int)`, because the only thing you can do with a `Foo` whose type you don't know is call `getBool` on it or `getInt` on it.  You use `Num` in your datatype, and `Num` has *no observations*, since if you have an unknown `a` with `Num a`, the only thing you can do by calling methods of `Num` is get more `a`s out, and nothing ever concrete.  So your `A` constructor

```
A :: (Num n) => n -> T
```

gives you *nothing* and you might as well just say

```
A :: T
```

`Integral`, on the other hand, has `toInteger` as an observation.  So you could probably replace

```
B :: (Num n, Integral m) => n -> m -> T
```

with

```
B :: Integer -> T
```

(we lost the `n` argument and replaced `m` with `Integer`).  I don't think this is technically equivalent since we could have implemented its operations differently than `Integral` does, but we're getting pretty technical at this point and I doubt you have need for it (I'd be interested in how if you do).